# LINUX DEBIAN 7 Wget error Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, wget

```
 --2016-10-10 14:44:22--  https://frie.se/ts3bot/sinusbot-0.9.8.tar.bz2
Resolving frie.se (frie.se)... 104.18.49.41, 104.18.48.41
Connecting to frie.se (frie.se)|104.18.49.41|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Dozen of reasons can lead to this error report by wget...
Like corrupt, self-signed, intercepted SSL cert, for example. Or misconfigured server.
It's impossible to suggest you something in particular with your output.

As long as your URL seems to be OK, it's more likely to be related to you Debian 7 box configuration, or network issues.

Try running wget with `--no-check-certificate` option first, to ignore any certificate-related errors...

It may provide you some info for headstart. I'd go into tcpdump or Wireshark, looking for TLS session details to shed some light on source of the problem next. *wget* source being another choice (worst case)